# get the ETAG value from the HttpResponse

Tags: java, http-headers, httpresponse

To get the content length we usually use `httpResponse.getEntity().getCotentLength()`. But to get the ETAG 
Is it supposed to use `httpResponse.getFirstHeader("ETAG")`? Both the `Content-Length` and `ETAG` are just headers of the response ,is the difference to access them due to the fact that the the `Content-Length` are mandatory but `ETAG` are optional?

Comment: at a guess, java? If so (or if not), please add a relevant technology tag. There are *many* different things called `httpresponse`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the content length is mandatory and the entity tag is optional so you can get optional values by : httpResponse.getFirstHeader("ETAG").